# Using VBA and a Form button to copy and paste in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I hope someone can help me, I need a button in Excel 2013 to carry out the following commands:

1. In "Sheet1" the range "A2:I2" is copied.
2. The value in A2 is looked up to determine an appropriate worksheet, which is activated and the copied range is pasted into the next available row in the range of B:J.
3. Once the data is pasted, the value of the cell in column A in the pasted row of the activated worksheet is returned to the user.

So for example:

When I input into Sheet1.A2 "technical report", and click on my button, it would copy Sheet1.A2:I2, then lookup the worksheet called "TEC", activate it, and paste the data into TEC.B2:I2.

In my "TEC" sheet, I have a pre-existing list of numbers in column A. When a data range is copied into TEC.B5:I5, the value of TEC.A5 is looked up and returned to the user (who is locked out of TEC and only has access to Sheet1).

Importantly, every time this happens, the data must be pasted into a new row, and therefore a new number is returned to the user.

---

I know this is a lot to ask but I have been trying to use bits of code with no results and I am not a very advanced VBA user so any help provided here would be really appreciated!

Code so far is:

```html
Sub button()

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:I2").Copy                          'copy document data
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Technical Report" Then
Sheets("TEC").Activate                                            ' check for type of document and activate relevant document worksheet
                  
ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Engineering Coordination Memo" Then
Sheets("ECM").Activate

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Critical Design Review" Then
Sheets("CDR").Activate

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Preliminary Design Review" Then
Sheets("PDR").Activate

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Qualification by Similarity and Analysis" Then
Sheets("QSR").Activate

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Qualification by Test Procedure" Then
Sheets("QTP").Activate

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Reliability Report" Then
Sheets("REL").Activate

ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Specification Compliance Tabulation" Then
Sheets("SCT").Activate

End If




 Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer   'code to select next empty cell in coumn B
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 2   'column B has a value of 2
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next



Paste

 ActiveCell.Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Select
 Copy
 Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5").Paste
 

End Sub
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you will not get someone to write the code for you on this site. Try adding the code that you've tried so far and asking specific questions on how to improve it.

Comment: Hi @TheEngineer so far this is what I've got:


Sub Save_Click()

Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2:I2").Copy


IfSheet1.A2 = "Technical Report"


 ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("TEC").Range(B, 10)


Sheets("sheet3").Range("B10:I10").PasteSpecial


End Sub

Comment: Add that code into the question as an edit. Reading code in comments hurts ones head.

Comment: @Matt have added it to the comments. Currently getting an 'object required' message.

Answer (score 0):

In general I don't like to use copy/paste in VBA but rather assign values to ranges. This way you don't have to move back and forth between sheets. The following will work assuming you have a header row in each worksheet you are moving data to (since rowCount is never returned as zero).

```
Sub button()

    Dim sheetName As String

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Technical Report" Then
    sheetName = "TEC"   ' check for type of document and activate relevant document worksheet

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Engineering Coordination Memo" Then
    sheetName = "ECM"

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Critical Design Review" Then
    sheetName = "CDR"

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Preliminary Design Review" Then
    sheetName = "PDR"

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Qualification by Similarity and Analysis" Then
    sheetName = "QSR"

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Qualification by Test Procedure" Then
    sheetName = "QTP"

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Reliability Report" Then
    sheetName = "REL"

    ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") = "Specification Compliance Tabulation" Then
    sheetName = "SCT"
    End If

    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim sourceCol As Integer

    sourceCol = 2   'column B has a value of 2

    With Sheets(sheetName)
        rowCount = .Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("B" & rowCount + 1 & ":I" & rowCount + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:I2").Value
    End With

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5") = Sheets(sheetName).Range("A" & rowCount + 1).Value

End Sub
```